# Identify and source replacement common-mode noise choke

Tags: inductor, damage

I have a circuit where the marked <strike>inductor</strike> common-mode noise choke in the image below is damaged.
I am having massive trouble sourcing this <strike>inductor</strike> common-mode noise choke anywhere. No results on AliExpress and Ebay.
I would be really grateful if someone can point me to a replacement <strike>inductor</strike> common-mode noise choke.
The circuit is from a MH-24 Nikon charger. The inductor code I can make out is **0R20A153 PC**.
[image]

Comment: That's not a simple inductor. It's a common-mode noise choke/filter.

Comment: Hi, yes it probably is. Novice here who can troubleshoot broken parts and replace them. I just went by the marking L1 on the board.

Comment: Questions about where to find parts is not really on topic here.

Comment: It is a last resort as I cannot spec the choke. Was hoping someone might have an idea what the inductance might be so that I can find an alternative.

Comment: I am guessing the 20 in R20A stands for 20mH.

Comment: R20 1.5mH something like this https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/Taiyo-Yuden/TLF9UA102W0R8K1/?qs=PzICbMaShUdpSqyaxiCPjA%3D%3D

Comment: This part is used for filtering noise coming in and going out of the psu. You can simply replace it with two wires if you wish to see if the rest of the circuit operates. Suffice to say the actual specs aren’t critical in terms of operation.

Comment: Thank you, all your comments were very helpful in troubleshooting!
Circuit is functioning again.

Comment: which characteristics does this specific CMC have? how has the problem been solved? is the current rating 0.2A and inductance 15mH?
i have the same problem and need a substitution part for the 0R20A153 Part. many thanks for responses